# System.Linq.Dynamic.Core - querying nested objects

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, lambda, dynamic

I've got a JSON file which I'm deserializing to an object which at a basic structural level has this:

Root

--- Sites

------ SiteProducts

----------ProductName

----------Quantity

----------Price

----------etc. etc.

I need/want to be able to query this structure dynamically (Site/SiteProducts is but one example of a number of similar objects I need to query) and have been trying to get Dynamic LINQ to work.

This LINQ statement gives me an output of a SUM of quantities matching a given product:

`json.Sites.Select(Function(s) s.SiteProducts.Where(Function(sp) sp.ProductName = "Widget").Select(Function(spd) spd.Quantity).Sum)`

However, I can't figure out the corresponding dynamic LINQ.  I thought this might work:

`jsonObj.Select("new (Sites.Select(SiteProducts).Where(it.ProductName=""Widget"").Select(Quantity).Count())")`

but no, because siteproducts doesn't contain ProductName.

Is this even possible with Dynamic LINQ?  I've looked at the dynamic lambda expressions but they look pretty complicated.  I guess I just need to know if I'm missing something obvious (like the ability to easily have a lambda function within my dynamic select/where) or is this just not possible?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Use JObject which is dynamic: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm

Comment: Thanks @GHDevOps but I'm not sure this helps - all this would give me is a JObject instead of a strongly typed version of my root object.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: You have to make up your mind. Do you want a dynamic object determined at runtime or a strongly typed object determined at compiled time? If the former use dynamic linq or simply a dynamic object. If the latter use a strongly typed class with an ORM.

Comment: Thanks @GHDevOps, perhaps I didn't word my question well but this is not about whether it's a dynamic object or a strongly typed object, it's about being able to QUERY that object dynamically.  In the end I went down a different road and using JSONPath with the Linq library in Newtonsoft was able to solve my problem.  Thanks anyway, and I must give a hat tip as your link to JObject set me on the right path :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the end I ended up using a bit of a pointer from one of the comments to the JObject object within the Newtonsoft library and came across the ability to use JSONPath to query an object dynamically.  This solved my problem (without Dynamic Linq library which, as far as I can tell, will not allow you to query nested array objects).

Link here for more info: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm

And a worked example:

`jObj.SelectToken("$.Sites[*].SiteProducts[?(@.ProductName == 'Widget')].Quantity")`

Thanks for the steer :)

Answer (score 0):

since its not clear that you want deserialize dynamically or to known class here it is a couple examples

1. create a json string from class
2. deserialize to class
3. deserialize to JObject

```
void Main()
{
    var root = new ROOT(){
        Price= 22.33M,
        Quantity = 2,
        ProductName = "Test",
        SiteProducts = { "Prod 1", "Prod 2" },
        Sites = new List<Site>() { new Site() {Name = "Test Site", URL = "http://google.com"}}
    };
    var JSONstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root).Dump();
    //deserialize to ROOT class
    var JObjclass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ROOT>(JSONstr).Dump("ROOT CLASS");
    //deserialize to anonimus JObject
    var JObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(JSONstr).Dump();
    
    JObj["Sites"][0]["Name"].ToString().Dump("");
    
    
}

public class ROOT
{
    public List<Site> Sites { get; set; }

    public List<string> SiteProducts { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public ROOT()
    {
        Sites = new List<Site>();
        SiteProducts = new List<string>();
        Quantity = 0;
        Price = 0;
    }

}
public class Site
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }

}
```

```
{
  "Sites": [
    {
      "Name": "Test Site",
      "URL": "http://google.com"
    }
  ],
  "SiteProducts": [
    "Prod 1",
    "Prod 2"
  ],
  "ProductName": "Test",
  "Quantity": 2,
  "Price": 22.33
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response @Power Mouse, but I think I've not asked my question in a specific enough way - this is not about being able to serialize or deserialize, it is about being able to dynamically query the resulting object (whatever that is).  I've ended up using JSONPath and will provide an answer for anyone else who finds this article in the future (myself included!)